# Interactive Google Spreadsheet to Google Doc edit not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I have several projects and they respect the same structure they have a table of 8 rows and two columns and I wrote so far a script that takes all the docs and then puts them in a table with the information as column.It is a container bound script and I want to be used by several users.I am blocked for a quite long time because I want to make interactivity if I modify in the table it will modify in the Google Doc and vice-verso.I begin I tried with the column date if I modify the date and then click on the url of the Google Doc to see the change but it doesn't work.This is my code :

***Edit this is my new modified code:***

```js
function modify_Date_Google_Spreadsheet_to_Google_Doc_Project(e) {
  
  find_columns_in_projet();
  Logger.log(">> The column URL >> " + COLUMN_URL );
  Logger.log("The column date where we will modify it " +  column_date_project);
  
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var sheet = tss.getSheets()[0];
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  
  //from the second line car the first line we have the headers
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastColumn).getDisplayValues();
  
  if ( ( e.range.getColumnIndex() == column_date_project )  )
  {
    var activeRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
    var URL = e.range.offset(0,1,1,1).getValue();
    Logger.log('The URL is : ' + URL );
    var body = DocumentApp.openByUrl(URL).getBody();
    Logger.log('The body is ' + body );
    if(body)
    {
      var ok = 0;                                    //for the moment we don't have the table to modify the values we've put in the spreadsheet 
      var numChildren=body.getNumChildren();
      var compteur=0;
      //while we don't find the table we will search
      while(ok ==0 && compteur<numChildren)
      {
        var child=body.getChild(compteur);
        /** =========We are concerned by the first table with at least 8 rows ===**/
        Logger.log('the type in the loop  ' + child.getType());
        
        //here is our table  **/
        if(child.getType()==DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE && child.asTable().getNumRows() >= 8)
        {
          //so the variable gets 1 >>  ok = 1
          ok=1;   
          
          /**  The number of rows in the Google Doc table **/
          var numrows = child.asTable().getNumRows();
          Logger.log('The number of rows is   ' + numrows);
          //Logger.log('The new date is ' + data[activeRow][colonne_date_de_projet-1]);
          /** we will loop in the table **/ 
          
          var k = 1;     //we know the information is at right so we don't loop we will replace the value 
          /**  is not working   **********************************************/
          //child.asTable().getCell(7, k).editAsText().setText( data[activeRow][column_date_project-1] )  ;
         
          
          /**** is working   ***/
          child.asTable().getCell(7, k).editAsText().setText( 10 )  ;
        }
        compteur++;       /** until we find our table **/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's a trigger on edit because I have another one in the project This is the Google Spreadsheed with the script inside : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k_kj98U__0Bk44gh0qRFpaVx0ru3sN1pSPGiMQwimxo/edit?usp=sharing and my folder with the Google Doc projects is here : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1x1m7tqfoSY6yW5gvwoIoh9jRPuiqwADO?usp=sharing Any idea is great :) thank you very much in advance [image][image]

Comment: This is a complex project and needs to be broken down into clear layers of responsibilities. We can help you with how to make a change propagate to **one** other document and simple stuff like these, but to have the kind of synchronicity that you aim for you need to develop an entire architecture that won't fit into one answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.The synchronicity  would be perfect but for the moment I'm not there in fact I think I am far away from that^^^^.This is why I started to do a simple think : the syncronisation of the date column so if I modify the date it will modify in the Google Doc so I seted it as a trigger from spreadsheet and on edit

Comment: When I saw your shared script, I thought that the error occurs at ``data[n][colonne_date_de_projet-1])`` in ``modify_Google_Spreadsheet_Date_to_Google_Doc_Project(e)``. Because ``data`` and ``n`` are not declared in this function and as the global variable. Is this related to your issue? If there are no errors, ``if ( ( e.range.getColumnIndex() == column_date_project )  )`` might be "false".

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me a lot! In fact the error I think comes from data[activeRow][column_date_project-1]  the if works because if I do the line     child.asTable().getCell(7, k).editAsText().setText( 10 )  ; it will place 10 in the Google Doc date field. For the date and n I didn't have errors at the start but I've modified the code in the post but still does't work  >>>  If you have any idea to solve this data[activeRow][column_date_project-1]

Comment: var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var sheet = tss.getSheets()[0];
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  
  //from the second line car the first line we have the headers
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastColumn).getDisplayValues();

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried another code that works only if I modify the date of the 4th project in this code I replaced only the

> data_sheet[activeRow ][column_date_project-1]  with
>   data_sheet[4][column_date_project-1] because activeRow  is undefined
>   so any idea to recover the row of the active cell when I edit the data corresponding cell is great.
>
> ```js
> /** working with 4 as the 4 row's date modifies****/
> function works(e) {
>   
>   find_columns_in_projet();
>   Logger.log(">> The column URL >> " + COLUMN_URL );
>   Logger.log("The column date where we will modify it " +  column_date_project);
>   
>   var tss_bis = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
>   var sheet_bis = tss_bis.getSheets()[0];
>   var numRows_bis = sheet_bis.getLastRow();
>   var lastColumn_bis = sheet_bis.getLastColumn();
>   
>   //from the second line car the first line we have the headers
>   var data_sheet = sheet_bis.getRange(1,1,numRows_bis,lastColumn_bis).getDisplayValues();
>   
>   if ( ( e.range.getColumnIndex() == column_date_project )  )
>   {
>     var activeRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
>     
>     Logger.log('The active row  is : ' + activeRow );
>     var URL = e.range.offset(0,1,1,1).getValue();
>     Logger.log('The URL is : ' + URL );
>     var body = DocumentApp.openByUrl(URL).getBody();
>     Logger.log('The body is ' + body );
>     if(body)
>     {
>       var ok = 0;                                    //for the moment we don't have the table to modify the values we've put in the spreadsheet 
>       var numChildren=body.getNumChildren();
>       var compteur=0;
>       //while we don't find the table we will search
>       while(ok ==0 && compteur<numChildren)
>       {
>         var child=body.getChild(compteur);
>         /** =========We are concerned by the first table with at least 8 rows ===**/
>         Logger.log('the type in the loop  ' + child.getType());
>         
>         //here is our table  **/
>         if(child.getType()==DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE && child.asTable().getNumRows() >= 8)
>         {
>           //so the variable gets 1 >>  ok = 1
>           ok=1;   
>           
>           /**  The number of rows in the Google Doc table **/
>           var numrows = child.asTable().getNumRows();
>           Logger.log('The number of rows is   ' + numrows);
>           Logger.log('The new date is ' + data_sheet[4][column_date_project-1]);
>          
>           /** we will loop in the table **/ 
>           
>           var k = 1;     //we know the information is at right so we don't loop we will replace the value 
>           /**  is working   **********************************************/
>           child.asTable().getCell(7, k).editAsText().setText( data_sheet[4][column_date_project-1] )  ;
>         }
>         compteur++;       /** until we find our table **/
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```